# How to properly use getDayOfWeek method

Tags: java, localdate

I have a homework and here is my task:

Create an object class which has:

- a private instance fields of the LocalDate data type called deadline
- a constructor which instantiates the field
- a get method
- a set method

The deadline cannot be on Saturday or Sunday - if it happens, the (IllegalArgumentException) exception with a message about inappropriate date (in the format dd.mm.yyyy) is thrown out. Demonstrate the method using appropriate and inappropriate deadlines. Hint: use the getDayOfWeek method to show the day of the week.

I have a problem a really do not understand how to use getDayOfWeek method properly and of course I tried do program from this side but my output is: `Deadline@2d554825`

I already tried use this method but I really do not understand which datatype it needs to return

```
public DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek() {
    // what should I return?
}
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Deadline {

    private LocalDate deadline;

    public Deadline(LocalDate DeadLine) {
        this.deadline = DeadLine;
    }

    public LocalDate getDeadline() {
        return deadline;
    }

    public void setDeadline(LocalDate deadline) {
        this.deadline = deadline;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Deadline first = new Deadline(LocalDate.parse("2017-02-03"));
        System.out.println(first);
        }
}
```

Comment: I'll give you 2 clues: 1) `getDayOfWeek` is an existing method exposed by [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfWeek--) class. 2) You have a `LocalDate deadline` and it must not fall on a Saturday/Sunday

Comment: To deal with 'Deadline@2d554825' you will want to override Deadline.toString() to do the date formatting.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to know name of day of week, do it like this:

```
LocalDate a = LocalDate.parse("2017-02-03");
System.out.println(a.getDayOfWeek().name());
```

This way you can compare given day of week with String such as "SATURDAY" or "SUNDAY".

Second, if you want to do

```
Deadline first = new Deadline(LocalDate.parse("2017-02-03"));
System.out.println(first);
```

You need to Override @ToString in your Deadline class. For example:

```
class Deadline {

...

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return this.deadline.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a proper `toString()` method and a localized name of the day of week.

You can achieve that by using the method `getDisplayName(TextStyle, Locale)`, which I will show in the code below.

There is another thing that comes up reading your assignment task:

> *The deadline cannot be on Saturday or Sunday - if it happens, the (IllegalArgumentException) exception with a message about inappropriate date (in the format dd.mm.yyyy) is thrown out.*

==> There is not `IllegalArgumentException` being thrown, there isn't even any check for invalid weekdays in your code. This `Exception` will not magically appear, you have to implement it.

Here is some example solution:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Deadline {

    private LocalDate deadline;

    public Deadline(LocalDate deadLine) {
        // check if the given date is a Saturday or Sunday and throw the desired Exception
        if (deadLine.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY 
                || deadLine.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The deadline to be set is not valid ("
                    + deadLine.getDayOfWeek()
                            .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.getDefault())
                    + ", "
                    + deadLine.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"))
                    + "). Please provide a deadline which is a weekday.");
        } else {
            // otherwise just set the deadline
            this.deadline = deadLine;
        }
    }

    public LocalDate getDeadline() {
        return deadline;
    }

    public void setDeadline(LocalDate deadline) {
        if (deadline.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY 
                || deadline.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The deadline to be set is not valid ("
                    + deadline.getDayOfWeek()
                            .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.getDefault())
                    + ", "
                    + deadline.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"))
                    + "). Please provide a deadline which is a weekday.");
        } else {
            this.deadline = deadline;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return deadline.getDayOfWeek()
                    .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.getDefault()) 
                + ", "
                + deadline.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this is now a Saturday, which will throw the IllegalArgumentException
        Deadline first = new Deadline(LocalDate.parse("2017-02-04"));
        System.out.println(first.toString());
    }
}
```

Please note that you don't necessarily have to use the localized display name of the `enum DayOfWeek`, but it may be useful to do so. You can also just call `setDeadline(deadline)` in your parametrized constructor instead of writing the same error handling there, but if you decide not to do, you will have to keep the redundant code.